# Rspec Helper Method Not Accessible to Features

Tags: testing, rspec, tdd, rspec-rails

I'm learning TDD and running some Feature tests and am having issues with a helper method.

I've pulled out the following method from the feature test:

*todo_helper.rb*

```
module Features
  def create_todo(todo_title)
    click_on "Add a new todo"
    fill_in "Title", with: todo_title
    click_on "Submit"
  end
end
```

However, I'm getting the following error when I run the Feature Test.

```
Failures:

  1) User creates todo successfully
     Failure/Error: create_todo 'Buy Milk'

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `create_todo' for #    <RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserCreatesTodo:0x007fb1f351b150>
 # ./spec/features/user_creates_todo_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.34992 seconds (files took 2.01 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/user_creates_todo_spec.rb:5 # User creates todo successfully
```

I have two tests that are pulling this method and they are both failing. Here is the one above:

*user_creates_todo_spec.rb*

```
require "rails_helper"

feature "User creates todo" do
  scenario "successfully" do
    sign_in

    create_todo 'Buy Milk'

    expect(page).to have_css '.todos li', text: 'Buy Milk'
  end
end
```

This is strange because I created another helper that I'm using for the *sign_in* method above and that is working fine, but can't figure out why the second one is not working. I isolated the create_todo method within the original feature and it passes within each Feature but not as a helper. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you require and include the module containing your helper method in the RSpec config (`spec_helper.rb` or `rails_helper.rb`):

```
require "todo_helper"
```

Within `RSpec.configure`:

```
config.include Features
```

Comment: Thank you. I had added the previous module in rails_helper.rb but didn't realize I had done it along the way. Now it'll stick in my brain.